# ¿Por qué siempre regresa a mi primer if?

Tags: javascript, function

```
    <html><div class="input-group date datepicker" id="hora_ini">
    <input type="text" class="form-control placementT" id="txt_hora_inicio" 
     value="00:00">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon 
     glyphicon-time"></span></span>
    </div></html>

    $("#btn_generar_acta").click(function () {
        var inicio_fecha = $("#txt_hora_inicio").val();
        var stt = new Date("November 13, 2013 " + inicio_fecha);
        var fin_fecha = $("#txt_hora_fin").val();
        var stt2 = new Date("November 13, 2013 " + fin_fecha);

        if (stt = !0) {
            alert("Debe de ingresar una hora de Inicio");
            $("#txt_hora_inicio").focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (stt > stt2) {
            alert("La hora fin no puede ser menor a la hora de inicio");
            $("#txt_hora_fin").focus();
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: no debería ser `if (stt == !0) {`?? notese el ==

Comment: Te falta un operador `=` extra a tu comparación para que quede de la siguiente forma `if (stt == !0) {` y además esa comparación tampoco te sirve porque `!0 = true` por lo que también seguirá entrando a tu `if` sin importar que fecha elija.

Comment: if ($("#txt_hora_inicio").val() == "") {
                alert("Debe de ingresar una hora de Inicio");
                $("#txt_hora_inicio").focus();
                return false;
            }

Comment: he probado con este y tampoco a funcionado....

Comment: Hace falta que pongas tu código html donde se vean esos elementos, para ver qué puede estar ocurriendo.

Answer (score 1):

La comparación debe tener dos signos "==" `if (stt == !0)`:

```
if (stt == !0) {
        alert("Debe de ingresar una hora de Inicio");
        $("#txt_hora_inicio").focus();
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres verificar que el campo "txt_hora_inicio" se encuentra vacio intenta con:

```
if($("#txt_hora_inicio").val() == ""){
        alert("Debe de ingresar una hora de Inicio");
        $("#txt_hora_inicio").focus();
        return false;
}
```

Recuerda tambien validar lo mismo para la hora final.

Comment: Esto es lo que estoy usando:                                                                           <div class="input-group date datepicker" id="hora_ini">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control placementT" id="txt_hora_inicio" value="00:00">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span></span>
                                            </div>

Comment: Si estas validando que este campo no sea "00:00" creo que no es útil que le agregues ese valor al momento de crear el input, en ese caso mejor agrégale un placeholder="HH:mm" y el valor se encuentre vacío.

Answer (score 0):

En la pregunta menciones que estas usando datetimepicker, pero no mencionas ¿cual? (de que librería). Un datetimepicker debería darte ambas, fecha y hora, pero tu esperas solo la hora, seguramente por eso Date() no reconoce el formato de la cadena que le estas pasando.
Revisa la documentación, porque la mayoría (o todos) de esos controles te pueden dar la fecha/hora ya como un objeto Date.
Por ejemplo, si usas el plugin de JQuery :

https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

verás que puedes obtener ese objeto mediante:

```
var d = $('#input').datetimepicker('getValue');
```

Comment: no hizo la diferencia @OctavioGalindo

Comment: Octavio, las respuestas no son para pedir aclaraciones sobre la pregunta, revisa por favor [answer] y realiza el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio.